# Why is tabcontrol not showing anything after loading xml data c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xaml, tabcontrol

I have created a xml file of tabcontrol and saved it . The data in the file is correct . But when I try to make the tabcontrol again reading this file it doest not , It loads the data inserts it into tabcontrol1 but does not display anything. I am using this code I am doing this on winform not wpf, what is the problem ?

```
// for saving

string sav = XamlWriter.Save(tabControl1);
File.WriteAllText("data.bin",sav);

// reading and making the tabcontrol again

string file = File.ReadAllText("data.bin");
            MessageBox.Show(file); // reading the xml data which is correct
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(file);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

tabControl1 = (TabControl)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(tabControl1.TabPages.Count));// check to see anypages loaded
```

Comment: I'm not sure WF controls are written to support xml serialization, not counting the fact that `XamlReader`/`XamlWriter` sound like WPF related.

Comment: can you put  XamlReader.load() in a temp varable to debug whether the casting to tabcontrol is a problem?

Comment: Thanks guys for reply , I got the solution !! , worked around . Instead of putting it in tabcontrol1 direct . I used a temp tabcontrol and added every page in temptabcontrol to tabcontrol1 through loop. It should have worked before only but dont know why it doesnt works .